# Allowing jenkins to access contents of currently logged in user folder

Tags: linux, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I am using Jenkins to build my project in a Linux machine. During build operation files are read from a source location and files are to be copied to a new destination location.The source and destination locations are input by the user from Jenkins UI. I want the user to be able to select any folder located within his/her home folder as source or destination. For example: /home/jdoe/folder.

Currently, any folder inside /var/lib/jenkins, with jenkins:nogroup user-group, can be selected. However, a folder inside /home/jdoe/folder with same (jenkins:nogroup) user-group, and with the same permissions as the folders within /var/lib/jenkins, cannot be selected. I get a permission denied error on trying to read or write inside /home/jdoe/folder.

What can I do to enable reading and writing to a folder within the home folder of the currently logged in user? Can I set up Jenkins in a certain way to be able to do that, or do I have to change group settings for the home folder?Could you suggest a good configuration for me to be able to make this work?

Would there be any difference in using Jenkins on an Windows platform?

Comment: You probably are missing the *execute* permission for *other users* for some directory in the hierarchy. Run `chmod a+x /home/jdoe`.

Comment: @DanielBeck Your answer is an acceptable one, if you could write it here as an answer rather than a comment, this question would have been marked as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that the folder is having `read-write access` for `jenkins user group`.

```
sudo chmod -R 77 /home/jdoe
```

Also as in comment by Daniel, grant `execute permission` on the `/home/jdoe` folder.

```
sudo chmod a+x /home/jdoe
```